# jSoup connect timeout работает некорректно

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Здравствуйте!

Имеется android-устройство, с *очень нестабильным* доступом в интернет, и на этом устройстве выполняется строчка:

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect("https://ya.ru/").timeout(10000).get();
```

Судя по документации:

> If a timeout occurs, an IOException will be thrown.

Но выполнение данного кода иногда занимает более 10 секунд.

Как так получается, если я явно устанавливаю таймаут?

PS. jSoup 1.9.2.

Спасибо!

Comment: а более 10 секунд это точно измерено или примерно?

Comment: @Herrgott, С точностью до секунд, например, 15.

Comment: @s8am а собственно, что Вы хотите от телефона с нестабильным подключение? Такие ошибки ведь не всегда проскакивают, выставите таймаут подключения более 20с

Comment: @GenCloud, Я хочу чтобы корректно работал таймаут, и не вижу связи между нестабильным интернетом и некорректным поведением таймаута.